# before using jquery to fadein in on mouseover.how to let hidden element take up space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseover

how to let element take up space when hidden, before using jquery mouseover to make it appear.

here is an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nj97k/

when i do visiliblity hidden, the icon no longer fades in on mouseover.

Comment: Use `visibility` or `opacity` in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially make opacity 0

```
<a id='posttext'class='flagpost' style='color:grey;' href='javascript:void(0)'>
    <i style="opacity: 0 " class='icon-flag'>This is an icon</i>Flag
</a>​
```

then do fades normally:

```
$('.flagpost').mouseover(function() {
    $('.icon-flag').fadeTo(500, 1);

});
$('.flagpost').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.icon-flag').fadeTo(300, 0);
});​
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nj97k/7/)

Answer (score 2):

You can either replace `display:none` with `opacity:0` on your element, or you could trigger the `mouseleave` event of your jQuery immediately to do this for you:

```
.icon-flag {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Or

```
$('.flagpost')
    .mouseover(function(){
        $('.icon-flag').fadeTo(500,1);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('.icon-flag').fadeTo(300,0);
    }).trigger("mouseleave");​​​​​
```